# Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(37,1): error CS8025: Parsing error

Tags: c#, unityscript

So today im making a game that requires a gamemanager, and i cant seam to figure out why the code wont work, 
i came across yet another error, below
Could anyone tell me maybe where i have gone wrong and help me correct this
errors are

```
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(30,41): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `{'
Assets/Scripts/GameManager.cs(37,1): error CS8025: Parsing error`




using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {
public List<Character> Characters = new List<Character>();
bool ShowCharWeel;
public int SelectedCharacter;
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    if (Input.GetKeyDown (KeyCode.C))
    {
        ShowCharWeel = true;
    }
}
//controls the weel for characactor change//
void OnGUI()
{
    if (ShowCharWeel) 
    {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(Screen.width - 256, Screen.height - 256, 512, 512),GUIContent.none, "box");
        foreach (Character c in Characters) 
        {
            if (GUILayout.Button(c.Icon,GUILayout.Width(64),GUILayout.Height(64)()
                {
                    SelectedCharacter = Characters.IndexOf(c);
                }
            }
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
}
}
[System.Serializable]
public class Character
{
public string Name;
public Texture2D Icon;
public GameObject PlayerPrefab;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this has been fixed now, im sorry to have wasted your time, after viewing my code again i stupidly noticed a mistake

```
if (GUILayout.Button(c.Icon,GUILayout.Width(64),GUILayout.Height(64)()
```

should have been

```
if (GUILayout.Button(c.Icon,GUILayout.Width(64),GUILayout.Height(64)))
```